# Not able to add line items to existing order using .net sdk

Tags: ordercloud

Using .net ordercloud sdk, I have these issues:

1- I am not able to create order that contains existing billing and shipping address ids (the error says "billing address/shipping address not found")
2- I am not able to add lineitem to existing order (the error says "object not found!")

Comment: What I did is, create a new buyer user, and then create a new Client using this new user's credentials. This way then I am using this new user's permissions to call other apis. Here in this case, although I did create the Order using the user's Client, but it seems I can only add lineitems to the Order using the Admin user's client instance.